# Add an inbox toggle to filter out messages from other sites

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, global-inbox

When I click the Inbox icon on the navbar on any SE site, I see messages/updates from *all* SE sites. But I sometimes only want to see those specific to the site I'm in (or a site and its associated meta).

I believe it would be a good idea if we had a toggle, perhaps somewhere on the top bar of the inbox, for filtering out the messages/updates from other sites, leaving just the current site's. I'm not a UI expert so I won't bikeshed the specifics of what kind of toggle (link-like text? [V]/[ ] graphic? Something else?)

Comment: I don't think it'd be particularly difficult to have such a toggle and do a quick client-side filter. But it would open the door to missed notifications on other sites. You only have a single "last inbox read date" variable for your account, and opening the inbox on any site with this toggle on would essentially mark everything read network-wide regardless if you saw them. Getting around that limitation would require completely rebuilding the inbox.

Comment: @animuson: Well, the toggle could be non-persistent, i.e. it wouldn't stick, so that when you click your inbox you always get the global latest. It would make the site-specific inbox a "second-class citizen", but that shouldn't be a problem, seeing how it hasn't even existed so far and people weren't clamoring for it all the time.

Comment: This view does exist, but it's buried in your profile: [Responses tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses)

Comment: @Laurel: Ok; but I suggest making it accessible in the inbox. Many (most?) users have either never noticed the 'responses' listing, or otherwise not have the "reflex" to go there as opposed to moving their mouse up to get to the inbox icon.

Comment: @animuson "Getting around that limitation would require completely rebuilding the inbox" -> like https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382693/289691?