# Inbox notifications vanish

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox

Since earlier today, the red badge to notify me of new inbox items vanishes when reloading the page or opening another SE page in a new tab (not opening the inbox in either tab). Can this new behaviour somehow be switched off again?

When opening the inbox, the new items are still highlighted, just the red badge is missing. Accessing the unread inbox via the api (https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread) will also still include these items.

(the green badge from rep notifications is not affected , this one stays put even when reloading the page)

OS: macOS 11.6.8

Browser: Firefox ESR 102.3

Comment: I also noticed this last night (on Chrome; Windows). Likely related to [Inbox improvements: marking notifications as read/unread, and a filtered inbox view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382693/348196).

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Yes, might be related. Still annoying if the notification silently vanishes without opening the inbox.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a bug. Actually, it just happened again with the notification about your reply.

Comment: I only saw your first comment because I simultaneously got an upvote and wanted to edit the question to say that the rep badge is not effected :P

Comment: We're checking into what might be up here. Thanks for the report.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Those referenced inbox improvements haven't been released yet. That being said, we have someone looking into this bug here shortly.

Comment: If it helps https://i.imgur.com/33xE3nx.gif I THINK this shows the bug.

Comment: Not sure if it's related but I'm noticing that chat notifications aren't coming as quickly as they should. I usually see them in my inbox within a minute but they're taking more like 10-15, which makes me feel like it's not considering the chat preference for "quicker notifications".

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Feel free to add that GIF in the post

Comment: When I first went to the Hot Questions page this morning the inbox had moved to the left, and clicking on it popped up an error. A few minutes later it moved back to the right, and it was working except for not showing the badge.

Comment: This seems to be fixed now.

Comment: @Barmar - nope, my notifications are still only showing up on chat.

Comment: @Mithical Maybe it's being phased in, and you aren't using the updated servers yet.

Comment: @Barmar Still experiencing the problem

Comment: Same, I got back to the site after few days away, there were four new items, no red number at all, I clicked anyway just to check, and saw the new items. My guess, partial publishing of the new inbox, maybe done for testing, causing some issues.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard My theory is that the code for the new inbox was safely stored in a closed box, but now that we get closer to Halloween, the code staged an escape last night when nobody was looking and now everybody at headquarters is running around trying to catch all the escaped code lines -- might not be the most accurate theory, but fun to imagine :P

Comment: We've identified the issue and prepared a PR for it. We'll work on getting it reviewed and built out in the morning. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Appears to be fixed. @Catija was the fix pushed already?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Yep! There'll be an update soon but I've changed the tag for the time being. :)

Comment: @Catija Thank you and the devs for fixing this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As reported, this got fixed and deployed this morning. Here's a fun spot the difference:

```cs
Current.GlobalCache.GetInt(key)
Current.GlobalCache.GetAsync<int>(key)
```

Turns out, `GetInt` actually returns a `long` - go figure.

Thanks for your patience and the report, and also way more [interesting inbox features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382693/209031) to follow

Comment: I bet that took a `long` time to figure out

Comment: OMG, just now realized there are two different @Kyle's here! :-D

Comment: So, to solve the riddle, you had to change to `Current.GlobalCache.GetAsync<long>(key)` in order to fix the bug?

Comment: Don't forget to cast *that* back into an int `(int)(await Current.GlobalCache.GetAsync<long>(key))`!!

Comment: Nobody better have more than `2147483647` inbox notifications, or the whole thing falls apart

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard, We're informally known as `kyle-east` and `kyle-west`

Comment: @Kyle haha! But who is which, and why? :-)