# New inbox notifications have broken keyboard shortcuts

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

As of rev 2022.10.27.42994, with the changes to inbox notifications, the keyboard shortcuts for the inbox have been slightly broken. With the old behavior, pressing <kbd>i</kbd> will open your inbox, and <kbd>esc</kbd> will close it, and the focus will no longer be in your inbox (i.e. you can press <kbd>i</kbd> again to open the inbox again, and pressing <kbd>1</kbd> won't take you to your first inbox item). (I tested this on a page running rev 2022.10.26.42986.)

However, with this update, closing your inbox using <kbd>esc</kbd> doesn't remove the focus. This means that the keyboard shortcut helper, if it's enabled, will stay open, you can't open it again immediately using <kbd>i</kbd>, and if I press <kbd>1</kbd> after closing the inbox with <kbd>esc</kbd> I'll still be taken to whatever that inbox item is.

[image: A screenshot of the inbox items keyboard shortcut helper being visible, even though the inbox itself is closed.]

Comment: I see no changes to inbox notifications, so must be some A/B testing? Kudos for being selected to get the change! :)

Comment: That said, there are some changes related to it, e.g. bold for unread reputation changes, and new bug redirecting to se.com when closing the inbox messages popup, so something is surely being baked.

Comment: This might be related to the [planned inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382693/335251), though as far as I know nothing should be changing for the public just yet. We'll look into it. Also potentially related: [Notification counter doesn't go away anymore after clicking outside the window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383270/335251), [Clicking to close the inbox redirects to the full inbox on stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383269/335251)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just pushed the fix for the issue. During the implementation of the new inbox features we had to touch existing code, too, and unfortunately we caused this bug.

Thank you very much for the report and even more for your patience. We're sorry you've experienced those issues and hope that the planned improvements will make up for it!

Comment: "during the implementation of the new inbox features we had to touch existing code, too" - this appears to be happening more and more recently, i.e. partial changes related to new features that aren't ready yet causing bugs. Isn't there a way to improve it by bundling the changes together, test this whole thing on dev/test platforms, and only then push it all together to production?