# Clicking to close the inbox redirects to the full inbox on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, global-inbox

After I open the inbox by clicking on the navbar icon, clicking on it again used to just close the inbox.

Today, the second click redirects me to my full-page inbox, `https://stackexchange.com/users/<userid>/<username>?tab=inbox`.

The workaround is to press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to close the inbox (although this doesn't clear the unread count). Another workaround is to install [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup)

In the console is this error from [`full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Js/full.en.js?v=9830c055969f):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'count')
    at g.setUnread (full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1:19841)
    at g.setUnread (full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1:34432)
    at g.setUnread (full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1:14055)
    at g.markAsRead (full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1:19669)
    at g.markAsRead (full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1:34182)
    at g.markAsRead (full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1:14055)
    at g.markAsRead (full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1:18279)
    at g.markAsRead (full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1:32156)
    at g.markAsRead (full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1:14055)
    at g.toggle (full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1:15386)
setUnread   @   full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1
setUnread   @   full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1
(anonymous) @   full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1
markAsRead  @   full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1
markAsRead  @   full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1
(anonymous) @   full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1
markAsRead  @   full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1
markAsRead  @   full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1
(anonymous) @   full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1
toggle  @   full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1
toggle  @   full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1
(anonymous) @   full.en.js?v=9830c055969f:1
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:3
r.handle    @   jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: Out of sudden frustration I found this post - my Inbox is now BROKEN - clicking the icon to close it, like I always do, suddenly starts navigating to the "view all" page. This is **horrid** - please roll it back!!

Comment: @Stu You can use the Escape key to close the inbox.

Comment: @Barmar - why do I suddenly need to change the way I work and have always worked? I'm using the mouse, not the keyboard!!

Comment: @Stu It's just a workaround until they fix it.

Comment: @Barmar Ah ok - so this is not by design then? Sorry, Still seething with frustration lol ;)

Comment: @Stu Yes -- don't you see the error message in the question? That's preventing the code that enables the second click processing.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I do now I've taken the time to properly read it  fwiw I see the same in the console too.

Comment: This might be related to the [planned inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382693/335251), though as far as I know nothing should be changing for the public just yet. We'll look into it. Also potentially related: [New inbox notifications have broken keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383262/335251), [Notification counter doesn't go away anymore after clicking outside the window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383270/335251)

Comment: This was indirectly useful as I was unaware of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) which I've installed for chrome - the console error is still there but at least it prevents the navigation so usability is restored ‎

Comment: @V2Blast too bad weekend just beginning, meaning waiting at least three more days until someone will be able to take a look. Thanks for the heads up anyway, and if possible try to nudge someone in high enough floor to have some policy "Do not push partial changes to production" as this keeps happening. (Partial changes leaking to production before features are published, sometimes developers do it on purpose to test directly on production as was the case with Saves, that were "alive" for weeks before being actually published.)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard: I think all of the bugs that have been reported are already in the process of being fixed (or have fixes ready and just need to be reviewed/tested before they go live).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just pushed the fix for the issue. During the implementation of the new inbox features we had to touch existing code, too, and unfortunately we caused this bug.

Thank you very much for the report and even more for your patience. We're sorry you've experienced those issues and hope that the planned improvements will make up for it!

Comment: Unsure if related to this but when I navigate to a post via clicking the link in my inbox, after a few seconds a lot of errors appear in the console, *Uncaught (in promise) {message: 'A listener indicated an asynchronous response by r…age channel closed before a response was received'}*

Comment: @Stu I don't see that. Check if it's related to extensions. I see lots of `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` errors that are due to blocking ads.