# Inbox notification counter doesn't go away anymore after clicking outside the window

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox

I noticed (since last few hours) that whenever I get a notification now and when I click on the notification icon, the notification window opens as usual. But the unusual thing is that even when I click outside this notification window (as shown in the gif below), that notification reminder is still there:

[image]

Before today, whenever I used to click outside that notification window, that reminder/counter used to go away but not anymore.

Is this a bug or an intentional change?

Comment: This might be related to the [planned inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382693/335251), though as far as I know nothing should be changing for the public just yet. We'll look into it. Also potentially related: [New inbox notifications have broken keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383262/335251)

Comment: Also, your original post about this on MSO: [Notification counter doesn't go away anymore after clicking outside the window](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421137/1478931)

Comment: @V2Blast Also one more thing has changed. If you click again on that notification counter/reminder then you'll be redirected to the inbox page for some reason. This also does not used to happen before. For example, just click 2 times on that notification counter and you'll be redirected to the inbox page of stackexchange.

Comment: Yeah, I think that it's intended to function as a link to the stackexchange.com page when JavaScript(?) hasn't yet loaded, or when middle-clicking the icon (or right-clicking and choosing to open the link)... But I don't think it should open the stackexchange.com inbox when just clicking on the icon from an open inbox. I'll let the devs know about that as well.

Comment: Also related: [Clicking to close the inbox redirects to the full inbox on stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383269/341145), which appears to be caused by an identical (if not the same) JS error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'count')`.

Comment: @SamOnela: Thanks, didn't realize it'd already been reported in a separate post. I'll pass that one on to the devs as well :)

Comment: It doesn't clear on all open tabs if clicked on one tab either. It did until today. Now you have to refresh the page to clear it or see new notifications.

Comment: I have this too. The notification won't go away until I click the offered link, which page might already be open anyway. And if I try to close the dialog by clicking again on the notification icon (as before), it opens my profile page! That's the job of the icon to its left. They have broken something that did **not need fixing**.

Comment: I also do not see any new notifications unless I actively refresh the page. This all seems very broken suddenly.

Comment: replicated on Edge 106.0.1370.52 on Win10

Comment: ... and also, even though I clicked through to a recent notification, it has reappeared some minutes later (the triggering pinged comment has not been edited).

Comment: It looks like (at least part?) of the planned inbox improvments have gone live as I am now seeing messages showing as unread below others showing as read, but no way to clear them without actually clicking on the unread message. And when I *do*, it reappears as unread again shortly after.

Comment: Going further back... I'm getting pinged when I wasn't specifically @pinged. I have enough brain to revisit a question I am interested in, without a robot trying to decide for me. Perhaps the next comment addressed mine, or it didn't. Please cremate the AI robot. There is already a mechanism to inform of activity.

Comment: FWIW, I noticed this when I got a series of notifications for comments on a followed question. The early notifications behaved normally, but after around 2022-10-27 05:45:00 UTC they had this new "sticky" behaviour.

Comment: Also, the unread items are no longer highlighted.

Comment: Also, I seem to be getting re-notified of already actioned notifications and often out of order?! Or the notification is delayed by some hours?!

Comment: ...and the notification counter (red block with a number) does not update unless I refresh the page?!

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, until we refresh the page that counter/reminder doesn't go away. For example, just few minutes ago, I got two notifications(as shown by the red circle with `2` written inside of it), so to get rid of that we have to refresh that page. It doesn't go away by itself when we say click outside the notification window as it used to do before this bug.

Comment: I feel like the problem is worse since this was posted. Now I'm getting notifications of new items in my inbox, but there is nothing in there when I open it in the dialogue box, but if I refresh the page the notification icon is gone and when I open the inbox there's a new notification in there. >_<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We just pushed the fix for the issue. During the implementation of the new inbox features we had to touch existing code, too, and unfortunately we caused this bug.

Thank you very much for the report and even more for your patience. We're sorry you've experienced those issues and hope that the planned improvements will make up for it!

Comment: At present, my inbox says 2. When I click it, I see 2 unread messages from 2 days ago. Of which, I already actually responded to one of them by clicking through the inbox. The 2 will not automatically go away, and neither will the "unread" status of the notification. Is this the currently intended way for this feature to be operating?

Comment: At the moment there is an issue with the notification count not always matching the number of shown notifications. This is an old problem with merging mulitple notifications for one post. Unfortunately it is much more visible with the new functionality in place.