# Keyboard shortcuts aren't marking inbox messages as read

Tags: bug, status-review, global-inbox, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

When you click on an unread inbox message with your mouse, it brings you to that item - be it comment, answer, chat ping, mod message reply, etc. - and marks the inbox item as read. However, that behavior is not mirrored when you use the keyboard to go to that same item, by using the <kbd>i</kbd> shortcut and then selecting an item with, e.g., <kbd>2</kbd>. Using the shortcut will still bring you to the message item, but the inbox notification remains marked as unread.

I did make sure to test that this wasn't a userscript-caused bug, and it occurs on both Chrome for Ubuntu 22.04 and Chrome for Windows 10.

This [isn't the first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383262/294691) bug related to keyboard shortcuts that the changes to the inbox have caused; it might be worth adding "test keyboard shortcuts" to the checklist when testing new changes on your dev instance.

Comment: Well, I'm finding the inbox items aren't always being marked as read and I _don't_ use keyboard shortcuts, so I'm not sure it's directly related.

Comment: They're being consistently marked as read when I use the mouse and consistently not when I use the keyboard; I just tested again with the notification from your comment. I first used the keyboard, and it remained unread; I then clicked with the mouse and it was marked as read.

Comment: It's certainly intermittent, I'm just sharing that I have _definitely_ observed the same symptom a lot lately, and not once was I using the keyboard.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I also never had even one case of inbox item not being marked read, and I click **many**.

Comment: They're not marked as read if you open them in a new tab, @AaronBertrand - maybe that's what you're experiencing?

Comment: @Mithical about new tab, it does mark the item as read for me. (Assuming you mean middle clicking, didn't try other methods.)

Comment: I've read both of these messages multiple times, in the same tab, in a new tab, but [they keep coming back as unread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfaD0.png).

Comment: @Mithical: Specifically, it doesn't mark the notification as read if you right-click and open it in a new tab. If you middle-click to open in a new tab, it should still mark as read (this is what I usually do).