# Notifications are not reloaded until a page is reloaded

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox, live-refresh

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a page.
2. Open the notifications inbox in the top right.
3. Close it.
4. Stay on the page until you get a notification.
5. Open the notification inbox in the top right again.

Expected: The new notification(s) shown there. 
Actual: The inbox shows the old notifications.

You need to reload the page and *then* opening the inbox will show new items. Or open any other page. The source of the problem is that inbox items are only loaded once.

This can also be seen by monitoring the network requests - reopening the inbox will not request the notifications again:

[image: Short demonstration: going to a page, then opening and closing the notifications inbox multiple times only shows one network request in the browser developer tools]

This is a new problem. I do not know exactly when it started but previously you could keep one tab open and only check your new notification through it. Now it requires constant reloading for each new notification.

Comment: Source of all inbox related recent bugs: [Inbox improvements: marking notifications as read/unread, and a filtered inbox view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382693/inbox-improvements-marking-notifications-as-read-unread-and-a-filtered-inbox-v)

Answer (score 6):

This is fixed now

> Open your inbox
> Notification arrives
> Close inbox - refreshed!