# Make active bookmarks visible again in the profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, saves

I don't do much curation these days, and I didn't have much use of bookmarks, but there was one specific area where these two intersected. I had a handful of high-profile Stack Overflow posts bookmarked (typical example: [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)), and seeing an indicator for recently active bookmarked posts meant I could help nip the "long tail of crap" effect in the bud.

Fairly often users post meant-to-be-helpful low-quality, and more importantly, redundant answers to such questions. Catching (and downvoting and commenting and delvoting and flagging) these answers early usually leads to the appropriate action on these posts (i.e. deletion, very often self-deletion).

Before the shift to "saves" I could see all these activity indicators in my profile on one page. I could see indicators of main-site responses alongside them (which was helpful as someone who gets a lot of chat notifications), so it was enough to have a tab open with my profile page. Now that we have "saves" the functionality is moved to a different tab altogether, and there's no activity indicator I've been able to find so far. I accidentally remembered to check one of these questions recently, and noticed a month-old needless answer with already 7 upvotes (and 2 downvotes; now 3). Unless a mod will be kind enough to delete it there's no chance the community will be able to take care of it now.

So my feature request is this: please figure out a way to keep changes on newly active "saves"ed posts visible [in the main profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=topactivity). I'd also note that even if I manually go to my "saves" page I only see creation dates, not modification dates, which could otherwise be a very high signal-to-noise ratio indicator (as almost all new answers to such questions should be deleted).

Comment: @bad_coder regarding your edit: thanks, I've now considered that meta post. The conclusion doesn't seem overwhelming, even an MSE mod commented that "_but turds just get the point across better_", and I don't even think of "crap" as synonymous with fecal matter (only half the slang meanings on the wiktionary are feces-related). It's also one of the words that's allowed in prime time US television (or whatever), so I'm not particularly worried about keeping using it here.

Comment: @bad_coder also, you have no right to single handedly censor certain words. If you feel offended by a word, flag the post and move on.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard we all know it takes a button click for me to roll back if I don't agree. No harm done in taking action first instead of asking.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858)  

Comment: to be clear, this is asking for it to be visible to the owning user only, right? not to everyone? (save lists are private)

Comment: @starball "of course"

Answer (score 6):

You're raising an excellent use case that I hadn't seen mentioned.

With the [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019) change the key idea is using *Saves* to **revisit posts faster**, and using the [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661) to keep up with changes to posts.

This is arguably better overall, and the upcoming [Inbox improvements: marking notifications as read/unread, and a filtered inbox view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382693) should allow to keep inbox notifications on followed posts marked as unread until you get around to them. (This can act as the substitute of the new activity indicator on the old bookmarks tab in the user profile.)

Taken together I think we'll be winning on functionalities and your use case will soon be fully covered.

Comment: I guess an indirect point of your answer is that I could also "follow" these posts instead of having them (just) "saves"ed. I bookmarked them before following became a thing. Then again getting full-fledged notifications would probably be too noisy for me. But I'll definitely give it a thought, thanks. Actually, having reread your answer, it's not an indirect point, but _the_ point, I just didn't understand at first. Sorry.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні we still don't know how the inbox notifications will work, I think the use case you raise here would make an excellent FR post under the announcement. Devs may want to consider adding options to not get a red notification in the inbox add the event to the list with a bold/highlight in the and configure that only for new answers... Seems perfect.

Comment: Frankly, I don't have high hopes for extensive customization. I'll be happy if they deliver something that works moderately well in the simplest of ways you can implement the thing.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні SE is changing, the new Saves feature came with excellent customizing. Better to get the FR in early while they're still developing it.