# Old inbox functionality for community I'm not a member of

Tags: bug, status-review, design, global-inbox

I have just noticed a bug with the [inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382693/381239)

I couldn't see this previously reported on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/381239)

When you click on your inbox in a community you aren't a part of you get the old functionality inbox.

I noticed this from clicking a Hot Network Question which took me to a post on Home Improvement SE (not a member of this) and having a notification that prompted me to click my inbox. I thought maybe that the inbox improvements were still being rolled out in phases so I went to a more popular site Academia SE (again not a member of) and the old functionality persisted. The new style inbox works on every community I am a member of.

Here is a screenshot from my view from Academia (not member):

[image: not member]

---

And my view Stack Overflow (member):

[image]

---

I also just tested this by going to Web Applications SE (not a member) - old functionality, joined the community and then the inbox changes to the new functionality.

Comment: New functionality only for members! Call now +555-555-555 and join!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I called, and was asked to give my bank account details, is this expected?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars weird ... please post your card number with CVV here. I'll check.