# Make an option for auto-reading all the inbox once it's opened

Tags: feature-request, notifications, top-bar

In the past once you clicked your notification box, all the unread notifications were immediately cleared (i.e. became read).

[Although this definitely was not comfortable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382693/inbox-improvements-marking-notifications-as-read-unread-and-a-filtered-inbox-v) for someone who receives dozens of notifications, there are people that do not attract the same amount of activity or generally just read all the notifications at once after the first click - that's me, for example.

This means that I have to have one extra click to clear all notifications, or probably *some moar* than one extra click since I often forget that new behavior, close the inbox and have to reopen it again to dispose of intrusive red numbers.

**Proposal**: make an option for auto-reading all the inbox once it's opened (i.e. introduce an optional behavior that was default prior to [inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live))

[image: proposed "auto-read on open" checkbox]

---

Oops, it looks like the top answer from the thread i linked contains the same request… lets hope it gets more attention then

Comment: Disclaimer: I built it, but I have a userscript I've made called [Inbox auto-read](https://stackapps.com/questions/9606/inbox-auto-read-a-userscript-to-mark-inbox-notifications-as-read-automatically) that automatically marks everything as read when the inbox is closed

Comment: This feature-request has kind of already been made :P See [Tinkeringbell's request](/a/384149/997587) (though without the specific detail of where the option input goes), and [related request by VLAZ](/a/384150/997587)

Comment: @user yeah, already noticed that once cocomac commented, I inserted into my post a couple of minutes before your comment 

Comment: No point posting the 50+ bugs/requests that are already asked/reported as new questions so closed as dupe. (Though time for feedback is long over, so any *new* bug/request should indeed be posted as new question, not in the announcement.)